# Linux - Is there a way to mount a compressed file that is not an archive?

Tags: linux, mount, compression

It's possible to mount a compressed archive in Linux as if it were a directory using tools like [archivemount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archivemount) or `gvfsd-mount`, both of which depend on [libarchive](http://people.freebsd.org/~kientzle/libarchive/).  This only works for "proper archives", though; collections of multiple files with a directory structure.  Is there a way to mount single compressed files?  In other words, mount a .bz2 as opposed to a .tar.bz2.

Previous discussions:

- [Mount a compressed file as a
  folder?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=813134)
- [Archive Mounter cannot
  mount single-file archives like
  .bz2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/435579)

Comment: @slm: That link does not answer the question. Zip files are archives of multiple files, bz2 files are not.  Are you sure it can be used with bz2 files?

Comment: Ah, I missed that last sentence of your Q. I'm not sure it can, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Why, yes there is, sort of. There's a FUSE filesystem called [fuseflt](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~thkala/projects/fuseflt/) that does almost what you want. Rather than mounting a single file, it mounts a directory. Within the mount, you can set up arbitrary filters. The [documentation](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~thkala/projects/fuseflt/latest/README) gives your specific example: mounting a directory full of zipped files so that they appear to be unzipped.

Comment: That looks promising, but I have yet to try it.